# Killing a spawned electron instance

Tags: node.js, child-process, electron, spawn

I am using Atom Electron for a project of mine. At some point in my code, I am using

```
var child = child_process.spawn(process.argv[0], [_path.app], {cwd: _path.resources, detached: true, stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe', 'ipc']});
```

to start another instance of Electron which is supposed to do.. well, stuff. Now, at some point the child Electron app could become unresponsive, and I would like to kill it. However, if I just go with

```
child.kill();
```

I am only killing one of the several processes that the Electron app is made of. So I am wondering: is there any better way to do this?

What I would like to get is to kill the child. Wipe it from existence. Banish it into the oblivion without asking for its permission. Is there any way to do this? My other option would be to send it a message in the form `please-die`, but since the child could misbehave I am not really sure that this solution will work and the child will seppuku.

Comment: Have a look here http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Nodejs-managing-child-processes-starting-stopping-exec-spawn

Comment: Wow! This is helpful! Will try to implement this, thanks!